# Using sed to find and replace code with indents

Tags: sed, replace, find, indentation

I want to find and replace code inside a file and sed is probably the best way to do this. However, I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for or follow any hints/tips that are close to what I need.

The block of code is on two lines and has indents and the formatting needs to remain the same.

Here's the original

```
<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="true" relayPath="true" 
     status="blacklist" targetUrl="http://localhost:8080" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>
```

The end result should be this

```
<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="false" relayPath="false" 
     status="spare" targetUrl="http://127.0.0.1/res/tempmaint.html" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>
```

UPDATE:
Here's what I've already tried to do but it didn't make any changes
what I've tried here are some of the commands I've tried.

```
sed -i -- 's#<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="true" relayPath="true" status="blacklist" targetUrl="http://localhost:8080" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>"#<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="false" relayPath="false" status="spare" targetUrl="http://127.0.0.1/res/tempmaint.html" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>#g' test.xml
```

```
sed -e 's#<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="true" relayPath="true" status=" blacklist" targetUrl="http://localhost:8080" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>#<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="true" relayPath="true" status="blacklist" targetUrl="http://localhost:8081" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>\'$'\n#g' test.xml
```

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Comment: `sed` is an inappropriate tool for the job if you have valid XML. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: What did you try and what was wrong with it? And please, instead of expecting your readers to guess the differences, explain what they are in your question.

Comment: apologies I haven't posted much before on stack overflow. I tried using ``` ```` to add in my code. I also tried using <!-- language-all: lang-xml -->  but the text disappeared, so I'm not sure what I did what wrong there.  

I was trying to use sed because I'm doing this on a Debian host. I'm not familiar with the parsers you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Renauld. Thanks for checking out my post. Regarding the differences, I'm not sure what's not clear, I've provided a the code before any changes and what the end result should look like. However, if you're not able to see the differences, I'll show them here again

Original code 
relayHost="true" relayPath="true" status="blacklist" targetUrl="http://localhost:8080"

After the changes
relayHost="false" relayPath="false" status="spare" targetUrl="http://127.0.0.1/res/tempmaint.html"

Let me know if that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(relay[^"]*"\)[^"]*/\1false/g;s/\(status="\)[^"]*/\1spare/;s|\(target[^"]*"\)[^"]*|\1127.0.0.1/res/tempmaint.html|' input_file
<url IPMask="" deny="" hostMask="" httpAllowed="false" relayHost="false" relayPath="false"
     status="spare" targetUrl="127.0.0.1/res/tempmaint.html" timeout="" urlPath="*.jsp"/>
```